# Tension of a string, based on Hz, string-weight and string-length

Tags: frequency, vibrations, string

I’m not a physics student. Instead I have an electric bass guitar :)

- I know my strings vibrating-length: **0.800 Meter**
- I know the total weight of this length: **0.016575 Kilo**
- I know my strings resonant frequency: **55.0 Hz**
- I know the wave-velocity: **88.0 Meter per Second**

From that, how do I calculate the tension (in Kilo or Newton)?

Comment: Use the equation for tension here to work out the value http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/202454/modelling-the-sound-wave-of-a-guitar-string-with-an-equation

Comment: Thanks ... but no thanks ... I have now spent 3 days starring at a multitude of wave-equations, that doesn’t address my precise problem. I’m simply too stupid to grasp them :/

Comment: For a fellow bass player: If you know the wave velocity, then $F_T=v^2\mu$ with units of newtons. $\mu$ is the mass per unit length. This is something that you can find in any introductory physics book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frequency of a standing wave on a guitar string is given by

$$f = \frac{v}{2L}$$

where $v$ is the velocity, and $L$ is the length of the string.  It can be shown by using the wave equation (which I'll skip, as it is a more complex derivation) that the velocity of a wave on a string is related to the tension in the string and the mass per unit length, which can be written as:

$$v = \sqrt{\frac{T}{\rho}}$$

where $\rho = m/L$, is the mass per unit length.  Combining these, we can write the frequency as:

$$f = \frac{\sqrt{\frac{T}{m/L}}}{2L}$$

Solving for tension, we have:

$$T=4mLf^2$$

Comment: Mmmm... yes ... it is precisely these equations I have been starring at, for 3 days in a row.
Could you please show me how my numbers fit into these ... like in a real calculation?

Comment: @Ole-Sauffaus You just need to put the numbers you gave me into this equation.  You have the mass $m = 0.016575 \text{ kg}$, the length $L = 0.8 \text{ m}$, and the frequency $f = 55 \text{ Hz}$.  This gives $T = 4(0.016575)(0.8)(55^2) \text{ N} = 160.446 \text{ N}$

Comment: Would that translate to:
T = 4 * 0.016575 * 0.8 * pow(2,55);
... Which seems to result in: 1.91097e+15
lol :)

Comment: @Ole-Sauffaus I'm not sure what you're using to calculate it, so I don't know what pow(2,55) is, but it seems like it would be $2^{55}$, which is why the number is so big.  Try pow(55,2).

Comment: GOD .... crap ... it is my tool that have wasted 3 days of my time! ... sorry ... My problem is solved. Thanks!