# At what mode does a stretched string oscillate in a free oscillation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, oscillators

I am unclear that when a stretched string oscillates , does it oscillate in its fundamental or in its overtones. And I want to know whether there are any instances where a stretched string oscillate in one of its overtones as its natural frequency?

[image: Like this]

Comment: Are you just asking about a stretched string of uniform density, eg a guitar string? You can get "interesting" effects with non-uniform strings.

Comment: Of course, it's easy to make a string vibrate at a higher harmonic by dampening it. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_harmonic

Comment: Related: [Why are the harmonics on a string controlled by where we pluck it?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/627685/157014) and [Why do harmonics occur when you pluck a string?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/111780/157014).

Comment: @PM2Ring No, I am asking about a normal string with no fretboard( like a sonometer string) with no dampening. So when its plucked does it vibrate in its fundamental. (if the length of the string= L and the wavelength of the transverse wave in the string=  λ)                                                                                                                                             then,                                          λ=2L

Comment: You should [edit] that info into your question. But in that case, gandalf61 has basically answered your question.

Comment: @PM2Ring Sorry but I am still quite unclear. So does a plucked string always have harmonics. If not plucked will it oscillate like a basic sine transverse wave (like the picture in the question)

Comment: Yes, the freely-vibrating string will *always* have some higher harmonics. You should get a sonometer (or guitar), and watch its waveform on an oscilloscope. If you want a natural resonator that has almost all its energy in the fundamental, get a [tuning fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuning_fork), and even they produce a mix of overtones initially.

Comment: Another fun thing to do is to watch a good quality video of someone playing a large harp. The video camera frame rate acts like a stroboscope, so you can see the waves on the longer strings, moving in slow motion.

Answer (score 5):

A string played on a musical instrument will oscillate in a mix of its harmonics, although its fundamental frequency will usually be the loudest single component. The exact mix of harmonics will depend on whether the string is plucked, bowed or struck with a hammer; the place on the string where it is plucked, bowed or struck; and the force with which it is plucked, bowed or struck (the "velocity"). In addition, the body of the instrument (known as its "sound box") will resonate with certain frequencies and amplify them, changing the quality or "timbre" of the note.